# Object browser in vba7 does not show WebClient Object members

Tags: vba, excel

I need to download and save a file automatically from a URI. I think I can use URLDownloadToFile from "urlmon" library but I wanted to use the WebClient.DownloadFile method.

I hoped it would be a cakewalk but for reasons beyond me, I am not able to view or use the members of the WebClient class in the VBA 7 IDE. I have already referenced the .Net 2 framework's System.tlb and am able to see the classes in the System.Net namespace but members for many of the classes are not visible and I cannot use them in my code.

I get a compilation error on trying to use a code like:

```
Dim Downloader as New System.WebClient

Downloader.DownloadFile("uri","filename")
```

Maybe I have not registered the .Net classes to be used in VBA and hence the problem but; the `System.dll` being referred to in my project is located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.tlb`

which confuses me even more. Also, it will really help if someone can detail out the process to reference .Net Framework libraries in VBA 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to use the .Net library in your VBA project, [it appears to be a bit more complicated than that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378542/net-object-from-vb6-without-use-of-regasm-exe?lq=1).

Comment: @Blackhawk: Thanks for posting that link :) That link just got deleted from the link that i posted :)

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of .Net libraries, I suggest using the MSXML library.  You can add it to VBA in the IDE by clicking "Tools" ---> "References..." and checking the box next to "Microsoft XML, x.x" where x.x is the most recent version.

Here is a quick test you can run:

```
Public Sub Downl()
    Dim xhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set xhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    Dim oFile As Integer
    oFile = FreeFile()
    Open CurrentProject.Path & "\test.png" For Binary Access Write As oFile

    Dim bdata() As Byte

    With xhttp
        .Open "GET", "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", False
        .send
        bdata = .responseBody
        Put oFile, 1, bdata
    End With

    Close oFile
End Sub
```