# How to insert a picture from the internet into VBA Excel Userform

Tags: excel, image, vba, internet-explorer, userform

I found some VB code [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?387841-Display-image-from-internet-in-a-Picturebox), but I need it for VBA. After reading this code I tried messing around with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056591/object-browser-in-vba7-does-not-show-webclient-object-members), but still trying to figure it out.  Also, someone else had this problem before as shown [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/819227-show-picture-from-webpage-on-userform.html), but there was no explicit solution.

The code I am working with:

```
Sub Image1Insert()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fbd7dcb2d47ddcd7e6a799bde3ec0ef6?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
    UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strPath)
End Sub
```

---

`UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strPath)`

or `UserForm1.Image1.Picture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strPath)`

Neither work, but it is the idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, is that a... salacious picture?

Comment: No, it is just my avatar from StackOverFlow.

Comment: Seems like you have to [download it first](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5fc7e8db-1bce-4b13-b049-00434757bed2/load-excel-form-image-control-from-web?forum=exceldev). Edit: oh ok =P

Comment: The problem is that I want the image to be used whenever someone opens up the workbook. That is why I need an online source.

Comment: Uh did you read the link? It downloads from the internet. Edit: wait, why can't you just insert image onto userform when you build it?

Comment: I get that it downloads from the internet, but then not sure how it would be referenced in somebody's drive. So you are telling me if I upload the image from my hard drive to the userform, then send the file to my friend, the image will appear on his computer?

Comment: I'll ping you tomorrow.

Comment: (Please don't add commentary about voting to your posts - it tends to get removed, and makes no difference to voting anyway - thanks).