# Embedding image from URL in an Excel Userform

Tags: vba, image, excel, userform

I'm fairly new to VBA, have been trying to work this one out but not having any luck.

I'm trying to create a product catalogue and have built a userform to allow new products to be entered on the first blank row of the spreadsheet. So far so good.

Where I'm getting stuck however, is that I need to embed a product image from a url in the userform (e.g. https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-coffee-cup-and-coffee-beans-on-table-261745823.jpg) so that the file is able to be ported from computer to computer without losing the images already loaded onto the spreadsheet.

Ideally I don't want to have to insert the URL itself onto the spreadsheet at all. When the user hits Submit, I want the userform to pull the image from online & insert it into column A on the first blank row of the spreadsheet & resize it to a particular width/height. (to be determined).

I've found questions kind of similar to what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113876/inserting-an-online-picture-to-excel-with-vba) & [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/819227-show-picture-from-webpage-on-userform.html) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271981/how-to-insert-a-picture-from-the-internet-into-vba-excel-userform). The questions either aren't answered, or I'm not sure how to make them fit my needs.

This is the code I have now, however it presents a runtime 424 object error, I've clearly missed something ><

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitForm_Click()

Dim StorePrice As Currency, SupplierPrice As Currency
Dim pic As String 'file path of pic

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Pricing")

'Finds the last blank row
LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

StorePrice = txtStorePrice.value
SupplierPrice= txtSupplier.Price.Value

ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = txtProductName.Text
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = txtStorePrice.Text
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = cboCategory.Text
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = cboSubCategory.Text
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = txtStoreLink.Text
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = txtSupplierName.text
ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = txtSupplierPrice.text
ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = txtSupplierLink.text
ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = StorePrice- SupplierPrice
ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = txtNotes.Text

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Pictures.Insert(txtImgUrl.Value)


'handler:
'MsgBox "Error"

End Sub
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this I would really appreciate it!!!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try [WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197535/2165759).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why do you have the runtime 424 object error. Can you specify which line of code gives you the error?

I would say this link [Inserting an Online Picture to Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113876/inserting-an-online-picture-to-excel-with-vba) has everything you really need.

You should declare an object variable for the picture

```
Dim myPicture As Picture 'embedded pic
```

And the repeat this every time you insert the picture:

You need to insert the picture to the worksheet by setting the value of myPicture object variable. In your case it would be something like this:

```
Set myPicture = Pictures.Insert(txtImgUrl.Value)
```

And then you add some details on how to position this picture on your worksheet

```
With myPicture
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse 'Unlock aspect ratio
    .Width = ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Width 'Picture width equal to cell width
    .Height = ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Height 'Picture height equal to cell height
    .Top = Rows(ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Row).Top 'Picture aligned to the top edge of the cell
    .Left = Columns(ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Column).Left 'Picture aligned to the left edge of the cell
End With
```

Comment: Hi @AdamW, thanks for replying!

I tried to update the code as you had suggested, but when I run it breaks at 

Set myPicture = Pictures.Insert(txtImgUrl.Value)

Comment: It just keeps giving me the runtime 424 object error. I've checked spelling and everything so that's fine. I have declared the Dim as suggested. 
I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Ok, so maybe there is something wrong with the URL. Have you checked what’s inside the txtImgUrl.Value ? Try to to step by with F5 and see what’s inside.

Comment: When I step into it, the line "Set myPicture = Pictures.Insert(txtImgUrl.Value)", myPicture = nothing & txtImgUrl = the url i entered from shutterstock to test.